# Use Fourier transform to solve the integral

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $f(t)=1-t^2$ , for $|t|<1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Compute the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ and use the result to find the value of the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t-t \cos t}{t^3}dt
$$

SOLUTION:

So the Fourier transform is pretty easy and I got $\hat{f}(\omega)= 4 \frac{\sin \omega- \omega \cos \omega}{\omega^3}$. How do I use this to compute the integral? Since there is an obvious connection between these, can I use the inverse theorem or Parseval's formula?

Answer (score 7):

I solved it myself, here is my solution if anyone else counter the same problem.

So I used Parseval's formula

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(\omega) \overline{\hat{g}(\omega)}d\omega
$$
and then I just took $\overline{\hat{g}(\omega)} = 1$ with $g(t) = \delta(t)$, combining this I simply got

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t- t \sin t}{t^3}dt = \frac{2 \pi}{4} \int_{-1}^{1}(1-t^2)\delta(t)dt = \frac{\pi}{2}\,f(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: Why your bounds in the last integral turned into $\pm1$ ?

Comment: I saw now that my problem was written all wrong -.-. Look how $f(t)$ is defined now

Comment: You then have a typo in your question. **Corrected now ! But has you said, only the value at $0$ does matter.

Comment: yes I saw it too, I'm sorry :)

Comment: No problem, good answer!

Answer (score 1):

If 
$$ \hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt$$
is the Fourier Transform of $f$, then we have the inverse Fourier Transform
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\omega)e^{i\omega t}d\omega.
$$
Then you get the integral by evaluating the inverse transform at $t=0$.

Comment: That would work too, thanks for pointing this out :)